# Programmatic Python Browser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, browser, screen-scraping, mechanize

I want to screen-scrape a web-site that uses JavaScript.

There is [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), the programmatic web browser for Python. However, it (understandably) doesn't interpret javascript. Is there any programmatic browser for Python which does? If not, is there any JavaScript implementation in Python that I could use to attempt to create one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be better off using a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to automate the scraping using a web browser, so the JS executes and the page renders just like it would for a real user.

Answer (score 8):

The [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) package nicely wraps [Google's V8 Javascript engine](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/) for Python.  It's particularly nice because not only can you call from Python to Javascript code, but you can call back from Javascript to Python code.  This makes it quite straightforward to implement the usual browser-supplied objects (that is, everything in the Javascript global namespace: "window", "document", and so on), which you'd need to do if you were going to make a Javascript-capable Python browser emulator thing, possibly by hooking this up with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Answer (score 5):

My favorite is [PyPhantomJS](https://github.com/kanzure/pyphantomjs). It's written using Python and PyQt4. It's completely headless and you can control it completely from JavaScript.

However, if you are looking to actually see the page, you can use `QWebView` from PyQt4 as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the project maintainer isn't able to maintain the project anymore. But it will still be compatible with the 1.4.0 release. You can switch to [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) without loss of funtionality (except for all the awesome and new features PyPhantomJS had in comparison, such as plugin support....). They're looking for someone else to take over maintenance (core devopment), so hopefully it won't die out. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is also spynner " a stateful programmatic web browser module for Python with Javascript/AJAX support based on the QtWebkit framework" : http://code.google.com/p/spynner/

Answer (score 2):

You could also try defining [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) page triggers on the pages in question, executing whatever operations you want on the page and saving the results of the operation to a local file, and calling Firefox from the command line inside your program, followed by reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend that you take a look at some of the options available to you at http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming - surprisingly this is coming up as a common question (i've found three on stackoverflow today, by searching for the words "python browser" on google).  if you do the same you'll find the other answers i gave.

Answer (score 1):

you may try zope browser

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=zope.testbrowser

Answer (score 0):

[Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python) or [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) are both reasonably good, and use headless Chromium to render pages and interpret JavaScript.

I'd pick Playwright out of the two, simply because it's backed by a larger entity, and supports Chromium/Firefox/WebKit out of the box.