# Python to read Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, python, date, screen-scraping

I am using BeautifulSoup to get data from a webpage.  The webpage provides a date, which I see when I open the page in Firefox.  However, when I view page source there is no date, just some javascript that generates the date.  I see there are some related questions on here, I see references to ajax and json, I am just an amaeteur programmer though and remain confused here.  Here is some of the HTML code which has the javascript code in it with the date I need.

```
<div class="match-details">
  <p class="floatleft">
    BARCLAYS PREMIER LEAGUE 

    <span>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
        var d = new Date(1345489200000);

        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var hours = d.getHours();                                        

        if (minutes < 10) { minutes = '0' + minutes; }
        var dmy = [day, month, year];
        var hm = [hours, minutes];
        if (SITE_EDITION == 'us/en') {
            var dmy = [month, day, year];    
        }
        var matches_local = dmy.join('/') + " " + hm.join(':'); 
        matches_local += "<span class='live-red'>*</span>";

        document.write(matches_local);
        })();                                                       
      </script>
    </span>

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Could you outdent the code a bit? There's no need for pushing it off the page...

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that code will output a date to the page when run in a browser. He wants to know how to get that programatically if he's screen-scraping with python

Comment: @TimPietzcker I edited it to fix indentation but we'd have to wait for people to review the edit and accept it

Comment: @appleLover as far as I know, without a full-fledged javascript engine like those that run in browsers this might not be possible to do. Have a look at http://phantomjs.org/ which provides a browser you can access programatically

Comment: Are you just trying to find the string `new Date(1345489200000);` and turn that into a Python `datetime` object? Or are you trying to read the page rendered by this JavaScript and extract a date from the resulting HTML?

Comment: abarnert, that is exactly what I want to do, turn the string new Date(1345489200000); into a Python datetime object.  At first I assumed those were useless numbers as I don't see a date inside of that.  Even now I still don't see how to turn that into a date.

Comment: i opened a new thread since it seems like i needed a better understanding of javascript, rather than using some crazy new library to solve this simple problem.  

problem solved here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179738/parsing-javascript-date

Answer (score 2):

`BeautifulSoup` is an HTML processing library.  You need a HTML + Javascript processing library.

Read up on this Question : [Programmatic Python Browser with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916711/programmatic-python-browser-with-javascript)

As that QA states...you basically either need to use a real browser -- via Selenium -- or use a python browser that supports javascript -- like Spynner.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I am looking at pyv8 unfortunately i am having a hard time getting it set up on ubuntu.  the people maintaining the pyv8 site recommend to use the prebuilt version but there is no prebuilt version for linux.  i am going to open a new thread specifically asking how javascript parses the the line above.  i think that will be simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear & edited my repsonse.  You need a HTML + Javascript processing library.  PyV8 will only let you run javascript.  It won't parse the page & tell you which javascript to run.  You need to have a javascript-supporting HTML browser to trigger the correct events and allow for the DOM to be manipulated.