# Parsing Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, python, date

A website I am looking at has the following code.

```
var d = new Date(1362236400000);
```

This javascript date object somehow encodes the following HTML output,

```
"2/3/2013 10:00"
```

Could someone please explain this encoding? I need to make a python script that manipulates those javascript numbers to recreate the HTML output.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: milliseconds, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is the [number of miliseconds since the epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). In Python that could be handled with the [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1362236400000/1000)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 2, 16, 0)
```

Comment: thanks so much Martijn.  I spent over 5 hours already trying various things like playing around with this number in a javascript console, trying to use pyv8 to run javascript in my python program and running spynner.  Your answer is just what i was looking for!!